# Creating a 5-way table in R

Tags: r

I’m hoping to create a 5-way table that displays counts of overlap between 5 binary variables.

Something like a correlation table matrix, but with counts of the number of times both of those binary variables were = 1.

So the table would have column headers a, b, c, d, e and rows a, b, c, d, and e.

I was thinking of creating a matrix using count variables, but am open to other suggestions.

Thank you!

I’ve tried using various table functions, but am struggling with only getting counts to display

Comment: since everything is binary, you could use matrix multiplication.  `t(X) %*% X` would work

Answer (score 4):

If the columns in a data frame are binary, one can create a table of counts where two columns both have the value of one as follows.

```
# set seed for reproducibility
set.seed(91701987)

# create a data frame of 5 columna

df <- data.frame(a = runif(100),
                 b = runif(100),
                 c = runif(100),
                 d = runif(100),
                 e = runif(100))

# convert to 0 / 1 values
df$a <- ifelse(df$a > .3,1,0)
df$b <- ifelse(df$b > .4,1,0)
df$c <- ifelse(df$c > .5,1,0)
df$d <- ifelse(df$d > .6,1,0)
df$e <- ifelse(df$e > .7,1,0)
```

Now that we've created some data, we'll use matrix multiplication to find the counts where pairs of columns both have the value of 1.

```
as.matrix(t(df)) %*% as.matrix(df)
```

...and the output:

```
> as.matrix(t(df)) %*% as.matrix(df)
   a  b  c  d  e
a 67 40 32 23 26
b 40 61 27 22 19
c 32 27 48 18 18
d 23 22 18 36 12
e 26 19 18 12 35
>
```

Now, we'll check the A / B cells (2,1) and (1,2):

```
# check the a / b value
t(df$a) %*% df$b
```

...and the output, which matches the cells in the matrix above:

```
> t(df$a) %*% df$b
     [,1]
[1,]   40
```